# Resize windows command line prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line

I'm working on a Windows xp machine. I wrote a program in assembly that outputs some text, and am trying to create a screenshot of the command line output (start->run->"cmd").

The problem is that the text initially printed by the program gets pushed up by later text and I cannot scroll to it.

I tried playing around with the width and height under properties => layout but it seems to resize the window itself (the borders) without resizing the textarea inside the window (text does not have more "room", but the window is bigger).

Does anybody know a workaround/solution for this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Resizing under the properties dialog should work (ensure you are resizing the width and buffer size, resizing the window alone should also increase the buffer), but if it doesn't work you could always:

- Redirect the output to a file:

  ```
  program.exe > C:\path\to\file.txt
  ```
- Check out [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/)

Comment: It's very easy to setup a shortcut with the size parameters you desire for your command prompt.... but I, too, and a HUGE fan of Console2.

Comment: You can also hit Alt-Space and go to the *Properties* tab.

Comment: You could also try conemu - https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/

Answer (score 6):

There's a setting on one of the tabs where you can set the buffer-size (how many lines it should store for scrolling).

**Edit:** You can find it in the Layout-Tab, Screen Buffer Size. Set the Height to the number of lines you wanna store for scrolling.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following to do this as well:

```
mode con:cols=x lines=y
```

For example:

```
mode con:cols=150 lines=80
```

You can create shortcuts that do this automatically:

```
cmd /k mode con:cols=150 lines=80

cmd /k mode con:cols=80 lines=40
```

Answer (score 1):

have a look at **[ColorConsole](http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Freeware/ColorConsole)** (it's free and portable), now you can either use **Faststone Capture** (a free and portable version can be obtained **[here](http://www.portablefreeware.com/?id=775)**) if you need a 'scroll screenshot' or use the ColorConsole feature to export the whole lot to HTML/RTF.

as a neat bonus you just got yourself a first class CMD replacement with a plethora of useful features such as favorite commands, copy/paste/cut functionality, tabbed interface, fast folder switch, etc.

Comment: I appreciate the reply.