# How to use Git in fullscreen

Tags: windows, command-line, git

I have been looking for ways to full screen my Git terminal screen on windows.

I tried tweaking the property settings but no luck.

I found few crazy hacks online , but could not get it to work! :(

I am at a loss to understand why I can't find an easy way to accomplish such basic thing.

Comment: Console applications can't be dynamically resized in Windows.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg You can change the window's settings and cmd's defaults to use more columns though (it's in the app icon's context menu). There's no reason to continue to suffer from 80 columns.

Comment: @DanielBeck yes thats what I did, the biggest I got does not fill the screen

Comment: @meda so what happens when you make it bigger? Just keep trying until the screen is full...

Comment: @MattDMo It wont take more the 2/3 of the screen

Comment: Also see http://superuser.com/questions/285984/how-do-i-full-screen-my-cmd http://superuser.com/questions/584027/can-you-dynamically-resize-windows-command-line-window http://superuser.com/questions/79026/resize-windows-command-line-prompt

Comment: I don't understand, when I right-click the shortcut and go to the `Layout` tab it lets me resize it as much as I'd like.

Comment: And just for the record, this is _not_ a duplicate. This question is about using git in fullscreen, and the linked question is about the Windows command prompt, which you do not have to use with git.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows I use TortoiseGit tool. for my opinion it is the simpliest way to work with repository and not to switch to another OS (Linux). Windows-friendly, I would say. there is an option to full view and you can make it in fullscreen.

Comment: I don't understand how this answer is relevant to the question; the asker is referring to the command-line.

Comment: Also, please don't assume that people who like Windows are clueless when it comes to the command-line and prefer GUIs. That's just not a general truth.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you are using the default Windows console window for git.

Consider using a different console. One often recommended is [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/).

Another option is to use Git from Cygwin; then you can e.g. use mintty.

Comment: Console2 doesn't have autocomplete nor copying text from console. Not really a replacement of Linux terminal.

Comment: @Tombart: Autocomplete is not provided by the console/terminal, but by the shell, such as bash or zsh (in practice, usually by plugins for the shell). And you can copy text, it just works a bit differently from other applications. See [How to copy text from Console2?](http://superuser.com/questions/132711/how-to-copy-text-from-console2) for details.